# Spring Boot app runs through the spring-boot-maven-plugin, but not the jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have a Spring Boot application that builds a jar successfully. However, when I run this jar, I receive an error:

```bash
mvn clean install
```

```bash
> java -jar target/my-app-api-0.0.local.jar

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
```

However, I am able to run the app through the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` via IntelliJ maven tab or through the `mvn spring-boot:run command`. The plugin is included in the pom:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

What could be a reason for this difference? I had previously received an error for not having a `main` method declared in the generated manifest, but added the maven-jar-plugin to specify this

```
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
Start-Class: com.proofpoint.app.MyAppApiApplication
Spring-Boot-Version: 3.0.2
Spring-Boot-Classes: BOOT-INF/classes/
Spring-Boot-Lib: BOOT-INF/lib/
Spring-Boot-Classpath-Index: BOOT-INF/classpath.idx
Spring-Boot-Layers-Index: BOOT-INF/layers.idx
```

Comment: Try `mvn package spring-boot:repackage` the run the jar file.

Comment: And how are you building the jar? Please show your full pom and not jut random snippets.

Comment: Added to my post how the jar was built with `mvn clean install`. I also added some of the generated MANIFEST file. Running `mvn package spring-boot:repackage` made no difference

Comment: Please add your full `pom.xml`, you shouldn't need the jar plugin. So are you really creating the jar the way you are stating or are you using (in addition) the export function of your IDE?

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing you didn't add the dependency to your POM, although I can't know without seeing it.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: @M.Deinum ...Do I really have to explain the difference between a plugin and a dependency to you?

Comment: In my defense, I blame lack of coffee. But the app is already running with the plugin so the dependencies seem in place else it would fail.